# Unification with constants

Tags: logic, unification

I am learning unification (Martelli and Montanari 1982 paper). I have a question about how the algorithm (Algorithm 1) deals with constants. Take these two equations:

$$
f(a) = c \\
f(X) = c
$$

where $a$ and $c$ are constants (zero-arity functions), $f$ an unary function and $X$ a variable. Note that there are no variables in the first equation.

The paper states: "If the two root function symbols are different, stop with failure; otherwise, apply term reduction." $f$ is different from $c$, I cannot apply term reduction, does that mean I have to stop with failure? My intuition would lead to $f(a)=f(X)$, $a=X$ and finally $X=a$.

Comment: If you want to unify $f(a)$ and $f(X)$ you can unify it with the unificator $s=[a/X]$. The Martelli Montanari algorithm just looks at the differences. So between $f(a)$ and $f(X)$ we have a difference at the third position, between $a$ and $X$. Because one of these is a variable we can just take the other as term and substitute with it. Martelli Montanari either fails when both differences are not a varible. Or the variable occurs in the term (so called failure because of occur check).

Comment: "Martelli Montanari either fails when both differences are not a varible." Does that ultimately mean that my example would stop with "failure"?

Comment: No, because $X$ is a variable.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What two terms are you trying to unify?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rereading the Wiki page gives me the answer: "So for example 1+2 = 3 is not satisfiable because they are syntactically different."

My example would fail on the first equation.